# Naming elements in a list in r

Tags: r, list, element, rename

I have a list with 21 character strings called "r1score.list". I made this list by reading in text files from a folder. Then I made each txt into a data frame and put those in another list called "r1.score". (You can ignore the function(x){sortertoDF(x)} because I'm calling a function that I've written somewhere else to manipulate the data).

```
r1score.list <- dir(pattern="*.txt")

> r1score.list
 [1] "p01_control.txt"   "p02_control.txt"   "p03_control.txt"   "p04_pq.txt"           "p05_pq.txt"        "p06_pq.txt"       
 [7] "p07_doce.txt"      "p08_doce.txt"      "p09_doce.txt"      "p10_dact.txt"      "p11_dact.txt"      "p12_dact.txt"     
[13] "p16_carm.txt"      "p17_carm.txt"      "p18_carm.txt"      "p19_cisplatin.txt" "p20_cisplatin.txt" "p21_cisplatin.txt"
[19] "p22_amsacrine.txt" "p23_amsacrine.txt" "p24_amsacrine.txt"

r1.score <- llply(.data=r1score.list, .fun=function(x){sortertoDF(x)})
```

Right now, I have named each data frame in r1.score by doing this:

```
names(r1.score) <- r1score.list
```

But I want to name each data frame by just the word that comes after the underscore. Meaning, if I call the first data frame in r1.score, I want it to have the name "control". If I call the fourth data frame, I want it to have the name "pq". If I call the last data frame, I want it to have the name "amsacrine", etc etc. I don't want to go through 21 txt files and give them new names so that I could do this. Is there a simpler way??

Thank you.

Comment: Your list looks like a character vector, not a list, as it is defined in R...

Comment: Please specify as a character vector not a list - quite confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to do with regular expressions (the funky pattern that is the first argument to `sub`):

```
names(r1.score) <- sub(".*_(.*)\\..*", "\\1", r1score.list)
```

The second argument is what we replace the value matched by the regular expression.  In this case it is a special symbol `\\1`, which is a reference to the part of the pattern matched inside the parentheses, `(.*)`. If you look carefully you can see that before the parenthesis we're matching `.*_` which means "anything ending in an underscore" and on the other side we're matching `\\..*` which means anything starting with a period (we need to use `\\.` because otherwise a period is treated as a wild card).

Comment: +1 here is mine : `gsub("(^.*\\_)(.+)(\\..*$)", "\\2", r1score.list, perl = TRUE)`:)